# Count frequencies and add a total sum

Tags: r, unique

I have a large data.frame containing these values:

```
ID_Path    Conversion    Lead    Path    Week
32342      A25177        1       JEFD    2015-25
32528      A25177        1       EUFD    2015-25
25485      A3            1       DTFE    2015-25
32528      Null          0       DDFE    2015-25
23452      A25177        1       JDDD    2015-26
54454      A25177        1       FDFF    2015-27
56848      A2323         1       HDG     2015-27
```

I want to be able to create a frequency table that displays a table like this:

```
Week       Total    A25177    A3    A2323
2015-25    3        2         1     0
2015-26    1        1         0     0
2015-27    2        1         0     1
```

Where every unique `Conversion` has a column, and all the times where the `Conversion` is Null is the same time as when the `Lead` is 0. 
In this example there is 3 unique conversions, sometimes there is 1, sometimes there are 5 or more. So it should not be limited to only 3.

I have created a new `DF` containing only `Conversion` that are not `Null`
I have tried using `data.table` with this code:

```
DF[,list(Week=Week,by=Conversion]
```

with no luck.

I have tried using `plyr` with this code:

```
ddply(DF,~Conversion,summarise,week=week)
```

with no luck.

Comment: Where did `A2323` come from and why the `Total` is 5 for that row? Seems to me that all you need is something like `addmargins(table(DF[c("Week", "Conversion")]), 2)`

Comment: Or maybe something like `reshape2::dcast(df, Week ~ Conversion, value.var = "Conversion", margins = "Conversion")`, still not sure where that 5 came from...

Comment: Ahh I missed that, it should be 3 and not 5. 
The A2323 was to illustrate that there were more Conversion points and not only the ones that you see in the first 6 rows

Comment: I have corrected the 5 to a 3, and added another line to show the A2323

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend dropping unnecessary levels in order to not mess the output, and then run a simple `table` and `addmargins` combination

```
DF <- droplevels(DF[DF$Conversion != "Null",])

addmargins(table(DF[c("Week", "Conversion")]), 2)
# Conversion
# Week      A2323 A25177 A3 Sum
#   2015-25     0      2  1   3
#   2015-26     0      1  0   1
#   2015-27     1      1  0   2
```

Alternatively, you could do the same with `reshape2` while specifying the `margins` parameter

```
library(reshape2)
dcast(DF, Week ~ Conversion, value.var = "Conversion", length, margins = "Conversion")
#      Week A2323 A25177 A3 (all)
# 1 2015-25     0      2  1     3
# 2 2015-26     0      1  0     1
# 3 2015-27     1      1  0     2
```

Comment: I found that your suggestion with `reshape2::dcast(df, Week ~ Conversion, value.var = "Conversion", margins = "Conversion")` worked like a charm

Comment: I just checked it as well, and it worked great as well! thanks for your help

Comment: Just a quick question regarding the base R solution, what does the 2 at the end of the code mean?

Comment: It means the margins type. If you want it column wise it will be 1. If you want it row wise it will be 2. If you won't specify anything, it will give you both. Try just `addmargins(table(DF[c("Week", "Conversion")]))` for example. You can also specify the margin functions using `FUN` (if you want something different from `sum` in your margins).

Answer (score 0):

An alternative solution using dplyr and tidyr:

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)

dt = data.frame(Conversion = c("A1","Null","A1","A3"),
                Lead = c(1,0,1,1),
                Week = c("2015-25","2015-25","2015-25","2015-26"))

dt %>% 
  filter(Conversion != "Null") %>%
  group_by(Week, Conversion) %>% 
  summarise(Lead = sum(Lead)) %>%
  ungroup() %>% 
  spread(Conversion,Lead,fill=0) %>%
  group_by(Week) %>%
  do(data.frame(.,
                Total = sum(.[,-1]))) %>%
  ungroup()

#     Week A1 A3 Total
# 1 2015-25  2  0     2
# 2 2015-26  0  1     1
```

Comment: Correct. I missed the point about how 0s are generated. Answer updated.